# Xubuntu 16.04 - Audio (Alsa, Pulseaudio...) stopped playing out right side of headphone

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I've tried almost every post here. Restarting alsa, reinstall all the packages.

This issue is seemingly random. Headphones plugged in, plugged them out for maybe 5 minutes, plugged back in, and now there is no way to get back right-side of audio. I've restarted laptop (Dell XPS) multiple times when restarting audio, deleting or trying configs...

I've tested multiple headphones (they all work outside this laptop), to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas how I can get the audio drivers to pick up the right side again like it did a few minutes ago? It's for realtek, XPS 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying an external USB enabled sound card. This fixed the issue, so it's safe to say it was a hardware issue with the sound card being old / maybe dusty / pins.

These external cards can be cheap to test if anyone else has this problem.